# how to query mongodb with inner id?

Tags: mongodb

The collection:

```
"team":{  
   "_id":3,
   "name":"team",
   "groups":{  
      "4":{  
         "name":"Red"
      },
      "5":{  
         "name":"Blue"
      }
   }
}
```

How to query the group by the group id "4"?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use $exists operator to query by key,

Mongo-shell command:

```
db.team.find({
    "groups.4": {
        $exists: true
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You tyr like this,

```
db.team.find({},{"groups.4":1})
```

(or)
based on $_id (criteria)

```
db.team.find({"_id" : 3},{"groups.4":1})
```